# Relational Database Modelling

Tags: rdbms

**Can a many-to-many binary relationship have no intersection data?**

I'm reading the book 'Fundamentals of Database Management Systems 2nd Edition' and in page 38, there is this question but the answer is not provided, just explain the many-to-many with an associative table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: yes, check page 129 for an example ;)

long one:
Intersection data are information that not belong to any of two entities of the M2M relationship, but they also don't describe the relationship.

I.e. Teachers and Students

A teacher can have many students, a student many teachers. The hours of lesson of each teacher with each student can be intersection data.

**Hours**

```
Teacher Student Hours
A       1       2
A       2       2
B       1       4
B       2       1
```

But we can also imagine this relationship without hours, for example if we are interested only in which students are in the class of each Teacher.

**Classes**

```
Teacher Student 
A       1       
A       2       
B       1       
B       2
```

This table continues to describe the relationship, but without intersection data.

Classes is the Associative Entity of the relationship Teacher - Student.

Hope this makes things a bit easier.